# Auto update two columns from 2 tables

Tags: sql, relationship, cascade, populate

Hello I am wondering of there is a way in a SQL server database schema relationship diagram using cascade or something similar which will keep two columns from different tables the same. The pk fk is using part_number. I am wanting the part_description to match in both tables without having to write queries.

dbo.Parts
Primary_key
part_number
part_quantity
part_description
part_location

dbo.part_numbers
Part_number
part_description

Comment: Why did you decide on such schema? It seems a bit redundant.

Comment: The datagridview is databinding automatically and filling in the part_description. It would be more code to fill it progromatically which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a trigger like this: on updating dbo.Parts table update dbo.part_numbers table and vice versa.
Here is a MSDN article about triggers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Thank you Tim. I am wanting to create a trigger in sql server that will run on update and insert which will keep the data the same for description based on the part_number which will remain the same as well. So if a person updates one table it should change the other as well and vice versa. Is there any greater detail which you can help. I am looking at the msdn and searching for examples. Thanks.

Comment: <code>
CREATE TRIGGER inserupdate
   ON  Parts
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
 declare @id1 int
    select part_number = part_number from inserted
    
    begin
        update dbo.part_number
        set dbo.part_number.part_description = dbo.Parts.part_dateReceived from inserted
    end
END
GO
</code> 
I am getting a multi-part identifier error on dbo.Parts.part_dateReceived

Comment: Sorry, Brandon, I'm an Oracle guy and never worked with SQL Server.

Comment: This worked one way but having a two way trigger would call one another. I ended up creating a view. There may be a way to do the trigger someway. I'm just not that skilled.

Comment: You can add a verification to trigger code, like "if this value already inserted in this table, do nothing".